# Looking for a more efficient way to implement this R code if possible

Tags: r, performance, processing-efficiency

I have the following R code that works but it's quite slow. I want to create a new column based on the values of an existing column in a R dataframe. But there's a catch/complication, I need to access and change a Global environment variable which holds a comparison value across observations.
I accomplish this using APPLY with a function on the rows of the dataframe. The function can write and read the external variable. This works but is slow. Is there any way of speeding up the process?

The value of drug in the first observation is the start BASE_VALUE.
What I'm trying to do is label the observations (drug value) which are different from the BASE_VALUE and are not substrings of the BASE_VALUE. The drug value of this observation then become the current BASE_VALUE and the process continues. In the example below, the 2nd "applesauce" value which is in the 3rd row of the dataset should NOT be flagged, as it appeared in the 1st line. This illustrates that I need to somehow store the value of the 1st row and be able to compare it with the 3rd row. That's why using the lagged value doesn't work and why I have the BASE_VALUE variable. Indeed I originally tried to use the lagged value till I realised this.

Reproducible code is below:

```
base_value <- ""
char_vector <- c("applesauce", "apple", "applesauce", "orange", "orange", "banana", "applepie") 

#change char_vector to a dataframe, the lastone column isn't completely necessary
df = data.frame(drug = char_vector) %>% 
mutate(lastone = lag(drug))

test_func <- function(row, output){
if (is.na(row[2])){
   #this is the first observation - set the drug value as BASE_VALUE
   base_value <<- row[1]
   return("Y")
 }else if (!is.na(row[2]) & row[1] != base_value & !grepl(row[1], base_value, fixed = TRUE)) {
   base_value <<- row[1]
   return("Y")
 }else {
   return("N")
 }
}


switches <- apply(df, 1, test_func)
cbind(df, switches = switches)
```

Tried above and it works. But would like to speed it up

Comment: Take a look at `accumulate`, from the `purrr`package. I don't have the time to test it, right now, but I'd define a function that returns the new `base_value` if `grep` fails, and `accumulate` the result. You'd then have a column of `base_values` and then its trivial to check when the value changes (e.g. `x != lag(x)`).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `accumulate` from the `purrr` pacakge to keep track of the `base_value`s, and then check for changes in it:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
char_vector <- c("applesauce", "apple", "applesauce", "orange", "orange", "banana", "applepie")
    
new_base <- function(old_base, value) {
  if (grepl(value, old_base, fixed = TRUE)) {
    return(old_base)
  } else {
    return(value)
  }
}

tibble(X = char_vector) %>%
mutate(base_value = accumulate(X, new_base),
       changed = ifelse(base_value != lag(base_value, default = ""),
                        "Y", "N"))
```

```
X          base_value   changed
applesauce applesauce   Y
apple      applesauce   N
applesauce applesauce   N
orange     orange       Y
orange     orange       N
banana     banana       Y
applepie   applepie     Y
```

With `accumulate` the value returned by the function is fed into the next iteration as the first argument, and is... well, accumulated, into the final result, which will be returned at the end of the recursion.  Just like `cumsum`, e.g.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a much more elegant solution than mine. I'll test it on real data and feedback the timings.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer was posted before OP edited their test data.]

You're making life too complicated.  A judicious combination of `lag` and `str_detect` can give you what you want without looping.

Get some test data by modifying the last line of your example:

```
original <- cbind(df, switches = switches)
```

Solve the problem

```
library(tidyverse)

suggested <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    switches = ifelse(
      row_number() == 1, 
      "Y", 
      ifelse(
        str_detect(
          lag(drug), 
          drug
        ), 
        "N", 
        "Y"
      )
    )
  )
identical(suggested$switches, original$switches)
[1] TRUE
```

Your example isn't big enough to make benchmarking sensible, but this is likely to be quicker than looping.  A base R solution is likely to be quicker still.  (Though, IMHO, at the expense of readability.) You should test on real life data sets to determine which is likely to be best in production.

For benchmarking, consider `microbenchmark`.

Comment: Hi Limey, the problem is the STR_DETECT doesn't look at the lagged value but at BASE_VALUE. If it was the lagged value I agree it would be straightforward. Apologies I think having the lagged value column made the example unclear. But you could remove it and the problem becomes clearer. At the moment the only use of the lagged column is to indicate the first row of the dataframe because the lagged value in that case is NA. I could have done that in another way

Comment: My code produces an identical example to your test code.  I believe it answers your question.  If you feel it does not, then please modify your question, perhaps by providing a modified test data set and explicitly stating what your expected output is.  [Since my code doesn't use `BASE_VALUE` at all, I don't see how `str_detect` can be "look[ing] at" it.  I handle the edge case of the first row by `row_number() == 1` in the outer `ifelse`.]

Comment: I think the issue is with my test data. If the char vector had {applesauce, apple, applesauce, apple}, say, using the lagged value would mean the 2nd applesauce was flagged, but actually it shouldn't be. This illustrates that I need to store a value to compare across many rows of the dataframe not just the previous one. I'll try and get a better example and edit my post above

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Though you can hardly blame me for not working that out based on the information I had! :=)  A variation of my code should still work.

Comment: Not blaming you at all Limey, appreciate the help! I've edited my post above. I tried to do it with a mutate and using base R but couldn't find a way to not access an external variable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we don't need a lagged vector at all. We can put the `grepl` logic in an `ifelse` function and put it in `acc`umulating `Reduce`. When we then make a `factor` out of it we can exploit the underlying integer structure and calculate `diff`erences. Where the base doesn't change, we get `FALSE`, where it does `TRUE`. Adding `+ 1` to it allows us to nicely subset the vector `c('N', 'Y')`.

```
> base <- function(x, y) ifelse(grepl(y, x, fixed=TRUE), x, y)
> char_vector |> 
+   as.data.frame() |> 
+   transform(
+     switches=
+       c('N', 'Y')[
+         1L + (c(1, diff(as.factor(Reduce(fun, char_vector, acc=TRUE)))) != 0)]
+   )
  char_vector switches
1  applesauce        Y
2       apple        N
3  applesauce        N
4      orange        Y
5      orange        N
6      banana        Y
7    applepie        Y
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(char_vector)
c("applesauce", "apple", "applesauce", "orange", "orange", "banana", 
"applepie")
```